# Is it possible to specify a custom "lib/" shards install directory?

Tags: crystal-lang

The default install directory for Crystal shards in a Crystal projects is "lib/". Is it possible to customize the path?

Answer (score 4):

It seems you can set an environment variable `SHARDS_INSTALL_PATH`. This is however not documented and should be approached with care.

Why do you need a different install directory anyway?

Comment: I just don't like `lib` or `libs` as a install directory.  I tend to use different programming languages in the same repo sometimes and the use of `lib` increases the possibility of a clash. (I realize it's not a good reason, but I still had to ask just in case it ever came up.)

Answer (score 0):

```
# This sets the install path when you do `crystal deps`.
# It needs to be an absoluete path, not a relative path.
export SHARDS_INSTALL_PATH="$PWD/my/dir" 

# This is needed for the Crystal compiler to the find the shards.
#  The Crystal compiler does not use SHARDS_INSTAL_PATH.
#  Unlike SHARDS_INSTALL_PATH, it can be a relative path.
#  You must also specify the place for the Crystal source directory
#  in order to find the Standard Lib .cr files:
export CRYSTAL_PATH="$SHARDS_INSTALL_PATH:the/crystal/src"

# Now you can do:
crystal deps                  # uses SHARDS_INSTALL_PATH
crystal build src/my-file.cr  # uses CRYSTAL_PATH
```

Source: trial-and-error and grep-ing the source code for both [shards](https://github.com/crystal-lang/shards) and [Crystal](https://github.com/crystal-lang).

Beware: As [Johannes Müller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668050/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-custom-lib-shards-install-directory/44670407) stated previously, this is undocumented.